# change column background-color on hover

Tags: css, hover, selector

I have a table with class .theClass.  The table only has two columns.

Is it possible to select the entire column and have the entire column affected on a hover event?

Want to change the background-color of all td in column when any td of that column is hovered.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a class to each column's td's. Then make a simple jquery hover function for all td's of each class

Comment: CSS does not have any way to select the "parent element".

Comment: while you might have to use a different solution for columns, there is a css solution for hover on rows: http://jsfiddle.net/gsUXP/

Comment: @Horen ummm... He wants columns, not rows. Rows are **easy**

Comment: @Neal: just adding information here that could be useful for some people who don't care if their data is horizontally or vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in CSS, and the fundamental reason is that columns do not constitute elements. You can use `col` elements, but they are really not column elements: they do not contain cells as children, and they can only be used to set some properties on cells, and thus there is no concept of hovering a `col` element.

Thus, even parent selectors would not help, as a cell has no parent or ancestor that would correspond to a column.

Answer (score 4):

In [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) I would solve it this way:

html:

```
<td class='sometdstyle'
    ng-class="{ 'active': isActiveCol[0]}"
    ng-mouseover="isActiveCol[0]=true" 
    ng-mouseleave="isActiveCol[0]=false">
```

controller or `ng-init` (the initial values):

```
$scope.isActiveCol = [ false, false ];
```

css:

```
.className td.active { background-color:black; }
```

-or-

```
.className .sometdstyle.active { background-color:black; }
```

If the matrix is bigger then 2x2 and the content of the cells is programmable, then `ng-repeat` solves the further complexities.

Comment: You could simplify it by replacing the array of bools with just a single number of the active column.

Answer (score 3):

Until the CSS4 parent selector is here, I think you will have to use JavaScript. Here is a jQuery solution that doesn't require any changes to the markup of the table. When a column is hovered, it calculates it's place within the row (thisIndex) and applies the class "active" to any column that has the same position (index) within it's parent row.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/obeyix/1

```
    var $td = $('table td'); // Place outside hover function for performance reasons

    $('td').bind('hover', function() {

        // Position of hovered column within this row
        var thisIndex = $(this).parents('tr').find('td').index( $(this) );

        // Add active class to all columns that have the same index as the hovered one
        $('table tr td:nth-child(' + (thisIndex+1) + ')').addClass('active');

    // Remove active class when mouse leaves a cell
    }).bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $td.removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: please tell me css4 will allow selectors inside of the declarations too.  I'm ready to make a complete hash of my pages!  ;))

Answer (score 2):

using CSS only we can not change the attributes as per the previous answers. but I had faced a similar problem in which I need to change the background color of the column of the cell hovered. I got a trick to solve my problem using

```
td:hover::after
```

you can check  https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/ to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a different class per column (ex: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, etc), then you can select and change based on the column number.

So (some very hacky code):

```
$('td').on('mouseover', function(){

    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var column = className.match(/\d+$/);
    var columnNumber = column[0];

    $('td.col' + columnNumber).(do something)
});
```

Comment: do u mean use jquery?  i don't understand.  could you write it out?  thank-you!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy see the code in my answer (needs to be worked on, but it is a start)

Comment: how to remove the class when mouseout after adding a class when mouseover?

Answer (score 0):

In <kbd>**AngularJS**</kbd> I solve this my way ***`with and without using controller`*** in `MVVM` and `MVC` both models, and I bet you can understand these ***easily***.

***With Plain Table Row (without `ng-repeat`)***

[image: Change table column background using AngularJS]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Change table column background using AngularJS</title>
    <style>
        .notth:hover{
            background:rgba(20,200,0,0.5);
        }
        /*If want to change hover background for thead rows also.*/
        /**** then remove the above style class.***/
        /*th:hover{
            /*background:rgba(20,200,0,0.5);*/
        /*}*/
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>

<table border="0" width="500">
    <thead>
        <col width="150"/>
        <col width="150"/>
        <col width="150"/>
        <th>First Column</th>
        <th>Second Column</th>
        <th>Third Column</th>
    </thead>
    <tr class="notth">
        <td ng-style="tdaStyle" ng-mouseover="tdaStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdaStyle={}">This is A</td>
        <td ng-style="tdbStyle" ng-mouseover="tdbStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdbStyle={}">This is B</td>
        <td ng-style="tdcStyle" ng-mouseover="tdcStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdcStyle={}">This is C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="notth">
        <td ng-style="tdaStyle" ng-mouseover="tdaStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdaStyle={}">This is C</td>
        <td ng-style="tdbStyle" ng-mouseover="tdbStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdbStyle={}">This is D</td>
        <td ng-style="tdcStyle" ng-mouseover="tdcStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdcStyle={}">This is A</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="notth">
        <td ng-style="tdaStyle" ng-mouseover="tdaStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdaStyle={}">This is E</td>
        <td ng-style="tdbStyle" ng-mouseover="tdbStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdbStyle={}">This is F</td>
        <td ng-style="tdcStyle" ng-mouseover="tdcStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdcStyle={}">This is B</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="notth">
        <td ng-style="tdaStyle" ng-mouseover="tdaStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdaStyle={}">{{tdaStyle}}</td>
        <td ng-style="tdbStyle" ng-mouseover="tdbStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdbStyle={}">{{tdbStyle}}</td>
        <td ng-style="tdcStyle" ng-mouseover="tdcStyle={'background':'rgba(20,200,0,0.5)'}"
            ng-mouseleave="tdcStyle={}">{{tdcStyle}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

***With `ng-repeat` directive***

[image: With <code>ng-repeat</code> directive]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Change table column background using AngularJS</title>
    <style>
        .notth:hover{
            background:rgba(20,200,0,0.5);
        }
        .tdStyle{
            background:rgba(20,200,0,0.5);
        }
        /*If want to change hover background for thead rows also.*/
        /**** then remove the above style class.***/
        /*th:hover{
            /*background:rgba(20,200,0,0.5);*/
        /*}*/
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
        app.controller("HomeController", function($scope){

            $scope.init = function(){
                $scope.data =
                    [{first:"This is A", second:"This is B", third:"Third is C"},
                        {first:"This is B", second:"This is C", third:"Third is D"},
                        {first:"This is C", second:"This is D", third:"Third is E"},
                        {first:"This is D", second:"This is E", third:"Third is F"},
                        {first:"This is E", second:"This is F", third:"Third is G"}];

                $scope.msg = "";
                $scope.reset_td_Styles();
            };

            $scope.reset_td_Styles = function(){
                $scope.td0Style = "";
                $scope.td1Style = "";
                $scope.td2Style = "";
            };

            $scope.changeClass = function(styleName, className){
                $scope.msg = styleName.toString();

                $scope.reset_td_Styles();

                switch(styleName){
                    case "td0Style":$scope.td0Style=className;break;
                    case "td1Style":$scope.td1Style=className;break;
                    case "td2Style":$scope.td2Style=className;break;
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeController" ng-init="init()">

<table border="0" width="500">
    <thead>
        <col width="150"/>
        <col width="150"/>
        <col width="150"/>
        <th>First Column</th>
        <th>Second Column</th>
        <th>Third Column</th>
    </thead>

    <tr class="notth" ng-repeat="item in data">

        <td ng-class="td0Style" ng-mouseenter="changeClass('td0Style', 'tdStyle')"
            ng-mouseleave="changeClass('td0Style', '')">{{item.first}}</td>

        <td ng-class="td1Style" ng-mouseenter="changeClass('td1Style', 'tdStyle')"
            ng-mouseleave="changeClass('td1Style', '')">{{item.second}}</td>

        <td ng-class="td2Style" ng-mouseenter="changeClass('td2Style', 'tdStyle')"
            ng-mouseleave="changeClass('td2Style', '')">{{item.third}}</td>

    </tr>

</table>

<div>td0Style is : {{td0Style}}</div>
<div>td1Style is : {{td1Style}}</div>
<div>td2Style is : {{td2Style}}</div>
<div>Message is : {{msg}}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As easier newbies can also understand easily.